# Pyspark dataframe not grouping by correctly

Tags: pyspark

I've had an application running successfully for months. Recently it started to fail because a method that takes in a pyspark DataFrame, groups it, and outputs the response somehow outputs a corrupt dataframe.

Here's example code of what I'm doing when everything fails:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, avg
group_by = pyspark_df_in.groupBy("dimension1", "dimension2", "dimension3")
pyspark_df_out = group_by.agg(sum("metric1").alias("MyMetric1"), sum("metric2").alias("MyMetric2")
```

If I print `print(pyspark_df_in.head(1))`, I correctly get the first row of my dataset. After grouping by a few dimensions and printing `print(pyspark_df_out.head(2))`, I get the following error. I get a similar error trying to do basically anything with this new grouped by dataset (and I know that the group by should result in data as I've eyeballed it to make sure).

```
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 9 contains a task of very large size (282 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
19/10/08 15:13:00 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 40)
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.VectorLoader.loadBuffers(VectorLoader.java:76)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.VectorLoader.load(VectorLoader.java:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$2.nextBatch(ArrowConverters.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$2.<init>(ArrowConverters.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$.fromBatchIterator(ArrowConverters.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anonfun$3.apply(ArrowConverters.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anonfun$3.apply(ArrowConverters.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/10/08 15:13:00 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 41)
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.VectorLoader.loadBuffers(VectorLoader.java:76)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.VectorLoader.load(VectorLoader.java:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$2.nextBatch(ArrowConverters.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$2.<init>(ArrowConverters.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$.fromBatchIterator(ArrowConverters.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anonfun$3.apply(ArrowConverters.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anonfun$3.apply(ArrowConverters.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 40, localhost, executor driver): java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.VectorLoader.loadBuffers(VectorLoader.java:76)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.VectorLoader.load(VectorLoader.java:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$2.nextBatch(ArrowConverters.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$2.<init>(ArrowConverters.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$.fromBatchIterator(ArrowConverters.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anonfun$3.apply(ArrowConverters.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anonfun$3.apply(ArrowConverters.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

19/10/08 15:13:00 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 39, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 42, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 49, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 46, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 45, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 50, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 48, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 47, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 43, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
19/10/08 15:13:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 44, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
```

Info about my environment:

- Spark Context version = 2.4.3
- Python version = 3.7
- OS = Linux CentOS 7

Has anyone run into this issue or have any ideas how I can debug/fix it?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a small example or got your data corrupted?

Comment: @cronoik I'm having a bit of trouble reproducing this issue with just a few rows of the dataset. In fact I realized today that the issue only occurs for the dataset on Oct 4, 2019. There must be something in this specific dataset that is causing the issue. I'm just not sure what. I tried converting the original `pyspark_df_in` to a pandas df so I could get summary stats on each column but it came back as an empty dataframe (even though I can literally print the top N rows in the pyspark df and see data is clearly there).

Comment: Well that means the data of the 4. Oct. is corrupted. What is your datasource? Is `pyspark_df_in.describe()` also causing this issue? If so, try to continusly remove columns and call describe() again and again until you know which columns are okay and which aren't.